# Why does GCC seg fault where clang does not on a textbook exercise?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Learning C using "System Programming with C and Unix" by Adam Hoover.  I have come across question from Chapter 4 that puzzles me greatly.  The question is as follows:

> In the following code, the first printf() reached
>   produces the output "14," but the second printf()
>   can cause a bus error or a segmentation fault. Why?

The original code from the book:

```
main()
{ 
  int *p;
  funct(p);
  printf("%d\n",*p);
}
funct(int *p2)
{
  p2=(int *)malloc(4);
  *p2=14;
  printf("%d\n",*p2);
}
```

My slightly modified "debugging" (printf all the things) version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void funct(int *p2);

int main(){
    int *p;
    printf("main p - address: %p\n", p);

    funct(p);
    printf("main p - address: %p\n", p);
    printf("main p value: %d\n", *p);
}  

void funct(int *p2){
    printf("funct (pre malloc) p2 - address: %p\n", p2);

    p2 = (int *)malloc(4);
    printf("funct (post malloc) p2 - address: %p\n", p2);

    *p2 = 14;
    printf("funct p2 value: %d\n", *p2);
}
```

I have compiled this sample using both gcc and clang (on ubuntu linux) and clang does not produce a seg fault for code that is supposed to do just that. I have puzzled over this for awhile now and can not imagine the why or how of this. Any insight welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're compiling on x64, `p2=(int *)malloc(4);` is not large enough.

Comment: You are allocating memory to an copy of the pointer passed to the function not to the pointer in `main()`. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is an UB. UB means it might crash or may not.

Comment: What fraction of C questions on Stack Overflow involve Undefined Behavior?

Comment: That's an actual *exercise*? Wow. One needs to pass the address of `p` (`&p`), if one wants to modify it in `funct()`.

Comment: I know the code is kind of horrible.  I believe the point of the exercise was to find what was wrong.  What I do not understand is why this horrible code does not seg fault when compiled with clang.  To be perfectly clear I think it should seg fault as it does when compiled with gcc.

Comment: @jeremy - Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer behavior is undefined. It didn't break in clang doesn't mean it **never** breaks on clang. Just you got unlucky on clang when the code didn't seg fault.

Answer (score 7):

```
int *p;
funct(p);
printf("%d\n",*p);
```

This is wrong. `p` is **passed by value**. So what ever made modification in the function doesn't affect `p` in the `main`. And dereferencing an uninitialized pointer behaviour is undefined.

What you actually need to do is -

```
funct(&p) ; // in main

void funct( int **p ){
   *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behaviour and doesn't have to result in a crash (or any other specific behaviour). A compiler is free to produce any code it likes for such cases. Since you asked why the code produced by clang doesn't crash, we'll need to dig into that code. Here's what clang trunk produces when compiling with `-O3` on x86_64:

```
main:                               # @main
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Build stack frame
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    movl    $14, %esi
    xorb    %al, %al                # no XMM registers used by varargs call
    callq   printf                  # printf(%edi = "%d\n", %esi = 14)
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    xorb    %al, %al                # no XMM registers used by varargs call
    callq   printf                  # printf(%edi = "%d\n", %esi = ?)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret                             # return %eax = 0
```

Since `p` is uninitialized, clang has chosen, today, to compile the expression `*p` to nothing at all. This is a legitimate transformation, because clang can prove that the expression has undefined behaviour. The value being printed is then whatever ends up in the `%esi` register at the time of the `printf` call (on my machine, that happens to be `-1`). This may not be what you expected, but that is the nature of undefined behaviour!